# AMD Processor Hax Kernel is not installed

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, bluestacks, haxm

I'm having problems with the Emulator on Android Studio.
First of all, when I'm trying to execute my app with the Android Studio emulator, appears me the following log:

> emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and
>   usable. CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Ok, searching I found that I have to install

> intelhaxm-android.exe

So I did it, but appers me a pop-up saying that my computer does not support Intel Virtualization technology.

Ok, searching I found that this is an option of my BIOS, but my BIOS does not support it.

So, may I give up? I do not know what else to do

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel virtualization works only on supported Intel processors. There is currently no such thing for AMD processors. But there's an amazing alternative! A couple of years ago, AMD partnered with a software startup to create a blazing fast emulator called [**Bluestacks**](http://www.bluestacks.com/). I previously used a machine with an AMD processor, and Bluestacks worked like magic on it!

Just install bluestacks on your PC. When you fire it up, it will show up as a mobile device in your IDE's list of supported devices. It runs as fast as real phone!

Comment: Oh yes thanks, I answered you with another account logged on my computer. It worked ok, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry I haven't seen your answer. Ok it worked, but it seems that is possible to run a "software" emulator for AMD processors. But Bluestacks worked perfectly. Thanks!