# HAX kernel module is not installed - AMD processor

Tags: android-studio, haxm

I've recently installed Android Studio and I'm trying to run a Hello World app to see that everything works as it should. Which it evidently doesn't. I've followed every step on the Android Developer site for setting up Android Studio, yet I get this error when I try to run my app:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

I searched for a bit and realized that HAXM is for Intel processors, and I'm running an AMD processor. I tried installing the emulator Bluestacks as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059977/amd-processor-hax-kernel-is-not-installed) thread but it didn't help at all. Has anyone got a clever solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might as well uninstall HAXM, only works with Intel processors.
A lot of answers in this forum have pointed to using genymotion (https://www.genymotion.com/) with AMD processors

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need to do to fix this issue:

1) Navigate to the following path:

C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

2) Run intelhaxm-android.exe as an administrator.

3) Once the installation is complete, Run your project and you will be able to run android emulator on your machine.

Hope this helps.