# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android

When I try to run my Hello application , the emulator gives this message. What is the sulotion?
This is the emulator view unfortunately.

[image]

**Error**

> 31/08/2018
>
> 16:32 Gradle sync started
>
> 16:32 Project setup started
>
> 16:32 Gradle sync finished in 3s 187ms (from cached state)
>
> 16:34 IDE and Plugin Updates: Android Studio is ready to update.
>
> 16:35 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 16:35 * daemon started successfully
>
> 16:35 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 16:35 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires
>   hardware acceleration!
>
> 16:35 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
>
> 16:35 Gradle build finished in 27s 847ms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AMD Processor Hax Kernel is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059977/amd-processor-hax-kernel-is-not-installed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in your error-output, running an emulator `x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!`.

**What does this error mean/where does it come from?**

Emulations run in a virtualized thread of your CPU. A CPU normaly got several physical cores (e.g. in QuadCore CPUs there are 4 physical cores). Virtualization furthermore subdivides these cores into multiple "virtual" cores, meaning it simulates more phyisical cores. You can read more information elsewhere on the internet. Here an extract from [geek-university](https://geek-university.com/vmware-esxi/what-is-cpu-virtualization/) which sums it up pretty short to the point:

> CPU virtualization involves a single CPU acting as if it were multiple
> separate CPUs. **The most common reason for doing this is to run multiple different operating systems on one machine**. CPU
> virtualization emphasizes performance and runs directly on the
> available CPUs whenever possible. The underlying physical resources
> are used whenever possible and the virtualization layer runs
> instructions only as needed to make virtual machines operate as if
> they were running directly on a physical machine.
>
> When many virtual machines are running [...], those [...]
> might compete for CPU resources. [...].

Emulators need this environment due to the highlighted reason: Its emulating an entire other system - In your case an Android smartphone.

**Solution**

Regarding you have an *Intel-CPU* (AMD should be somehow analog), this should solve your problem.

As general note (this seems to be solved in OPs question since its not in the error log): Make sure `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` is installed in your Android SDK (check under *Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools*)

Also as note if somebody wants to check if he has OPs problem coming from a more generic error: Run this command in the command line (needs `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)` to be installed in your SDK):

```
C:\Android\YourApp> C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd YourAVDName -netspeed full -netdelay none

# The First is your path to your SDKs emulator.exe; use the path you installed the SDK in
# -avd needs a name of an existing AVD you set up in the AVD Manager in Android Studio.
```

The possible outcome is (if HAXM is already installed and hardware acceleration is your poblem):

> emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.3.0 (build_id 7196367)
> (CL:N/A) handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf emulator: ERROR:
> **x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!** CPU
> acceleration status: VT feature disabled in BIOS/UEFI More info on
> configuring VM acceleration on Windows:
> https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows
> General information on acceleration:
> https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.

Note that I used an AVD with x86_64 here.

To solve the error you have to restart your PC and enter your BIOS. Search for you CPU-preferences (can often be found in an `Advanced`-options tab). Somewhere there you'll find a setting called `Intel Virtualization Technology` which presumably is disabled. `enable` and restart your computer.

Now your AVD should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into bios and enable VTX. This allows the emulator to use hardware virtualization.

Comment: hoe can go to bios and enable vtx??
can you help me ?

Comment: how can do that??
please help me

Comment: search your motherboard brand key for bios, if thats too much try your luck by pressing F2,F10,Delete while starting your PC

Comment: my camputer dont support vtx. wa=hat can i do? 
can i continue android???

Comment: do you have android phone?